# Override <f:ajax> rendering with a custom renderer

Tags: ajax, jsf, custom-renderer

I would like to override the output of the default `<f:ajax>` rendering. Is there a possibility to override the handling of the `<f:ajax>` tag respectively the renderer of this tag?

Comment: [What problem exactly are you trying to solve for which you possibly incorrectly thought that this all would be the right solution?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: As you can see by the comment above, short is not always good ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your fast response !i have several <f:ajax> tags in my xhtml sourcecode. When rendered to the frontend i want to avoid inline javascript. I just want to put it into a <script> block. Then add a "nonce" tag and add this "nonce" tag to my CSP header to make it XSS save. I already did this for commandButtons and it works. But a commandButton's Renderer is easy to override. And thats the problem: i don't know how to override the generated output of an <f:ajax> tag :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the `<f:ajax>` renderer by creating a custom [`ClientBehaviorRenderer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/render/ClientBehaviorRenderer.html) implementation and register it as `<client-behavior-renderer>` in `faces-config.xml` on renderer type `javax.faces.behavior.Ajax`.

```
public class YourAjaxBehaviorRenderer extends ClientBehaviorRenderer {

    @Override
    public String getScript(ClientBehaviorContext behaviorContext, ClientBehavior behavior) {
        return "alert('Put your JS code here.')";
    }

}
```

```
<render-kit>
    <client-behavior-renderer>
        <client-behavior-renderer-type>javax.faces.behavior.Ajax</client-behavior-renderer-type>
        <client-behavior-renderer-class>com.example.YourAjaxBehaviorRenderer</client-behavior-renderer-class>
    </client-behavior-renderer>
</render-kit>
```

Do note that there's a [`@FacesBehaviorRenderer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/render/FacesBehaviorRenderer.html) annotation anologous to `@FacesRenderer`, but when there's already a specific renderer type registered in any `faces-config.xml`, it would always have precedence over the annotation. Since this is already provided by JSF impl itself, the annotation becomes useless.

For reference, Mojarra uses [`com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.AjaxBehaviorRenderer`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.faces/jsf-impl/2.2.0/com/sun/faces/renderkit/html_basic/AjaxBehaviorRenderer.java#AjaxBehaviorRenderer) and MyFaces uses [`org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.html.HtmlAjaxBehaviorRenderer`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.myfaces.core/myfaces-impl/2.2.0/org/apache/myfaces/renderkit/html/HtmlAjaxBehaviorRenderer.java#HtmlAjaxBehaviorRenderer) for this purpose.